# How do you select data from PostgreSQL database, but if no data is present for a given day, then return 0?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, date, rails-postgresql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT created_at::DATE, count (*) 
FROM messages      
WHERE city = 'los angeles'     
GROUP BY created_at::DATE
```

Which works great. The challenge is that if there are no messages for a given date, then it returns no record for that date. How do you make the above query return the date and 0 if there are no messages on that date, ***for all days*** between a given date and today?

Working in PostgreSQL 8.3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need a table of all the dates you are interested in, as it may contain dates not in your messages table.  If you have, or build, this table then left join with the messages table and do count on a column that table--it will return 0 where nothing matches the join.

```
select d.created_at, count(m.messageId)
from possibleDates d
left join messages m
    on d.created_at = m.created_at
group by d.created_at
```

Answer (score 2):

Typical way is to have a separate calendar table with all of the dates in it, left joined to your table on date column, and then some sort of ifnull(x, 0) statement [whatever the function is for PostgreSQL] or case statement to return 0 when the left-join on the date returns null or 1 when it is not null.  Then you can do your normal group by and use SUM(x) instead of count().

Comment: the name of the function is COALESCE( a,b,c,... ) which returns the first non-NULL argument (from left to right).

Answer (score 2):

Very often, when you want to fill in zeroes for missing entries in a series, the answer in PostgreSQL involves the `generate_series` function.  (Search Stackoverflow for lots of similar questions and answers.)  In your case, use something like this:

```
SELECT ts::date AS date, coalesce(count, 0) AS count
FROM
  (SELECT created_at::date, count(*)
   FROM messages
   WHERE city = 'los angeles'
   GROUP BY created_at::date) AS m
  RIGHT JOIN
  (SELECT *
   FROM generate_series(timestamp '2011-07-01',
                        timestamp 'today',
                        interval '1 day')) AS series(ts)
  ON m.created_at = series.ts
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: +1 but... wasn't `generate_series(timestamp, timestamp, interval)` introduced in 8.4? (He's using 8.3.)

Comment: @Denis: Indeed.  Well, either upgrade or pick one of the other answers.

Comment: Actually, you don't really need timestamp to generate the series of days: `select current_date + s.a as dates from generate_series(0,14,7) as s(a);` This works in 8.3.